# Mysql Query Takes 142 seconds to execute

Tags: mysql

I have the following query. product_sub_locaions table has 701269 rows. I have added index only to every field which is used in joins. but it still takes 138 seconds.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    P.sku,
    PL.name,
    L.name,
    SUM(PSL.qty) as total_qty
FROM
    product_sub_locations PSL
    INNER JOIN products P ON P.id = PSL.product_id
    INNER JOIN categories C ON C.id = P.category_id AND C.is_finish_good = 1
    INNER JOIN sub_locations SL ON SL.id = PSL.sub_location_id
    INNER JOIN locations L ON L.id = SL.location_id
    INNER JOIN locations PL ON PL.id = L.parent_location_id
WHERE
    1 = 1
GROUP BY
    P.id, L.id
ORDER BY
    P.sku, PL.name, L.name
```

This is a Query Log showing the time taken
[image: This is Query Log showing the time taken]

When I apply to explain keyword this gives me the below output. can anyone explain to me how to understand explain result?

[image]

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in the manual which would be very difficult to condense into an answer here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: is there any website where can I learn about query execution optimization from the tutor? Anyone who can teach me in depth

Comment: should I need to use MySQL enterprise database?